# Generate a set with integers for certain bits

Tags: integer, set, bit

I would like to have a mathematical expression which describes a set of integers.
This set of integers should conform to the following.

Suppose I have 10 bits. I want to generate all integers which are made up of for example bit 0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10. So for instance the set should contain for example:

- 0, because 0 * 2^0 + 0 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^8 + 0 * 2^9 + 0 * 2^10 = 0
- 1, because 1 * 2^0 + 0 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^8 + 0 * 2^9 + 0 * 2^10 = 1
- 2, because 0 * 2^0 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^8 + 0 * 2^9 + 0 * 2^10 = 2
- ...
- 259, because 1 * 2^0 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^3 + 1 * 2^8 + 0 * 2^9 + 0 * 2^10 = 259
- ...

So the size of this set would be 2^7 = 128 elements, because we have 7 relevant bits.

The mathematical expression should look a bit like: {n:Nat | n >= 0 && n < 2^11 && ...(do something with relevant bits)... }

FYI I need to generate a Set of natural numbers for the language called MCRL2. http://www.mcrl2.org/mcrl2/wiki/index.php/Home.

Comment: Yes this is a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

in C, that would be:

```
int bits[] = {0,1,2,3,8,9,10};
const int length = sizeof(bits)/sizeof(int);
const int setSize = 1<<length;
int set[setSize] = {0};

for(int i=0; i<setSize; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j<length; j++)
      if(i&1<<j) set[i]+=1<<bits[j];
}
```

depending on which things are compile time constants and which are not, you might need to modify it a bit.